# How do I set boot parameters in the installer?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu and burned it to a disc.  The installer loads just fine, but will not find my hard drive.  Basically I need to set the `nolapic` boot parameter for it to find my HD controller.

Is there a way for me to set the boot parameters on the installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the boot menu, hit the F6 key and add that option at the end of the line before the "--".

[image]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options

Comment: Isn't that boot menu only present in the Server edition?  I don't see that with the Desktop edition.

Comment: you need to hit a key at the initial liveCD boot to get that menu iirc. If you could confirm that that would be great.